# Camel & spring ignoring @Produce and @EndpointInject

Tags: java, spring, messaging, apache-camel

I'm having a simple `MessageProducer` class that sends messages to a direct channel using camel's `ProducerTemplate`

Here is the code

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class MessageProducer {

    @EndpointInject(uri = "direct:app.out")
    protected ProducerTemplate template;

    public void sendEvent(Object payload, String eventName) {
        Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        headers.put("eventName", eventName);

        template.sendBodyAndHeaders(payload, headers);

        log.debug("Sent message {}", payload);
    }

}
```

When I debug this I found template to be null when this runs in a webapp, but it works in a spring Junit test.

I can't understand whats gone wrong.

Comment: might be a stupid question, but do you scan for components, so that the MessageProducer class gets picked up and initialized by spring?

Comment: Yeah the spring bean post processor needs to kick in, to let the IoC run. The Camel Test Kit does this automatic and hence why it works from unit tests.

Comment: @Claus, you are right, adding a Post processor did the job.

Comment: Can this question be marked as answered?

Comment: @Claus, there needs to be an answer to mark this as answered :)

Comment: Ah okay, let me put up a answer then.

Comment: Could one of you provide some details about how you fixed this please?

Comment: @JasonDay I forgot to include [BeanPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) in my context for endpoint to be injected using [EndpointInject](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/EndpointInject.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah the spring bean post processor needs to kick in, to let the IoC run. The Camel Test Kit does this automatic and hence why it works from unit tests.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to do this.? I created a new spring beanpostprocessor but what do i need to do in it.